# Images do not load in Rails development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have the following line of code:

```
<img src="<%= image_url ("/slides/hotel.jpg") %>" style="opacity:0;" alt="slidebg1" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left bottom" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source https://rubygems.org
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'headjs-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Development.rb:**

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.serve_static_assets  = true
```

I am running in Windows 8 and I gave rake assets:precompile and it completed fine. But the image does not load. I am sure that image exists under that specified directory. In my case, the image exists under `assets/images/slides/hotel.jpg`. I had tried giving the file path as `/assets/images/slides/hotel.jpg`, `/images/slides/hotel.jpg` and `/slides/hotel.jpg` and all 3 does not work.

**Error:**

```
Started GET "/slides/hotel.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-07-28 21:03:04 +0530
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/slides/hotel.jpg")
```

Comment: Can you show your `config/environments/production.rb` files content

Comment: config.cache_classes = true                                                      config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true                                                    config.assets.compile = true                                                  config.assets.compile = true                                                                                  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

Comment: Do you have `config.assets.digest = true`

Comment: @Nermin: Yes it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the image exists under `assets/images/slides/hotel.jpg`, so the path returned by `image_url` must be `/images/slides/hotel.jpg` (More info about assets paths in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets))

**Solution:**

```
<img src="<%= image_url('slides/hotel.jpg') %>" style="opacity:0;" alt="slidebg1" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left bottom" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
#                        ^---- Just remove the "/" here
```

**How I found-out:**

Little bonus, to help you find-out, next time you run in a similar case

From your rails app directory, in a terminal, start `rails c`

```
# Include the helper whom define image_url
irb(main):001:0> include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
=> Object

# Test the output of your actual code
irb(main):002:0> image_url "/slides/hotel.jpg"
=> "/slides/hotel.jpg"
# As you can see the path is incorrect because it does not start with '/images'

# Test the output after removing the heading slash
irb(main):003:0> image_url "slides/hotel.jpg"
=> "/images/slides/hotel.jpg"
# Correct output as the path starts with '/images'
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately, I am still unable to get my images to the site. Started GET "/javascripts/default.js" for ::1 at 2015-08-01 16:29:31 +0530
[2015-08-01 16:29:31] ERROR Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your hos
t machine.
        c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
        c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
        c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'

Comment: Stuck here for long now.

Comment: That's obviously another problem. Restart your server and try again

Comment: I had missing gems and I could resolve the issue. Many Thanks @Benjamin: I give you the deserved bounty. Cheers :)

Comment: Stack Overflow says 13 more hours. Wait on.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use [image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path)

For example

```
<%= image_path "/slides/hotel.jpg", style:"opacity:0;", alt:"slidebg1", 'data-bgfit'=>"cover", 'data-bgposition'=>"left bottom" 'data-bgrepeat'=>"no-repeat"%>
```

Comment: No luck Nermin. Issue prevails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try two other variations:

(1) `image_url ("slides/hotel.jpg")` (I can't imagine it's this basic and that `image_url` is adding a the extra slash...)

and

(2) `asset_url ("hotel.jpg")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In application.rb, add the below lines:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

If slides directory is in assets directory then

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "slides")
```

and if slides directory is in assets/images directory then

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "slides")
```

and then try to load image

```
<%= assets_path "/slides/hotel.jpg", style:"opacity:0;", alt:"slidebg1", 'data-bgfit'=>"cover", 'data-bgposition'=>"left bottom" 'data-bgrepeat'=>"no-repeat"%>
```

Hope this will work for you.